# What Does “BBS” in TCPDump Output Mean?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ios, tcpdump

I've recently implemented stricter firewall rules, and I keep seeing the Apple devices on my local network attempt to reach out to `192.168.1.156` or `192.168.1.152`. In an attempt to understand what it's doing, I ran `tcpdump` and received this output:

```
19:36:05.273166 IP 192.168.22.8.53058 > 192.168.1.156.bbs: Flags [S], seq 2685942121, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2363049810 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:36:14.889388 IP 192.168.22.8.53064 > 192.168.1.152.bbs: Flags [S], seq 3567670609, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2054024907 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Can anyone help explain what the `bbs` port/protocol is, and/or why Apple devices keep trying to talk to these seemingly random IPs outside of their subnet? To be more specific, it's both iPhones and the Apple TV doing it, but not the homepods on the same network.

I’ve read about the Bulletin Bus Service, but I haven’t found any information on how or why it would be used by certain Apple devices, especially to an IP that isn’t in use.

Comment: tcpdump gets the service/protocol names for port numbers from `/etc/services`, which is roughly based on historic port number/protocol registrations maintained by IANA. Many of those registrations are decades old and long abandoned. It means nothing. Run tcpdump with `-n` to see the port numbers instead of the often-obsolete names. It's better to google "tcp port nnn" and see what modern sites that try to track what modern protocols use which ports say is known to use that port number.

Comment: @Spiff thank you! I knew it had to mean something, even if it was irrelevant to the original traffic. Now to see what Apple is trying to do on port 7000 to a private address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the comment by @Spiff I was able to find out it was trying to send traffic over port 7000/tcp, which according to a couple [Apple discussion pages](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250472145) is [for Airplay](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251386214). It appears that Apple devices remember the IPs of Airplay destinations, and continuously try to connect to them.

[Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) does not indicate it uses port 7000 for anything, though this explanation lines up with my experience. In any event, it doesn't appear malicious, even if it is annoying to see in my firewall logs.